# How to parse LocalDateTime with leading spaces?

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, formatting, java-8

I'm trying to parse dates from html pages using LocalDateTime. And I couldn't come up with solution to make the following test pass.

(Using TestNG) First row always fails

```
static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss u");

    @DataProvider(name = "dateTimeFormats")
public Object[][] dateTimeFormats() {
    return new Object[][]{
            {"Mon Jan  5 06:41:07 2015", LocalDateTime.of(2015, 1, 5, 6, 41, 7)},
            {"Sun Jan 25 00:48:23 2015", LocalDateTime.of(2015, 1, 25, 0, 48, 23)},
            {"Mon Aug 14 07:58:00 2006", LocalDateTime.of(2006, 8, 14, 7, 58, 0)}
    };
}

@Test(dataProvider = "dateTimeFormats")
public void testParsePostDateTime(String dateTimeString, LocalDateTime expectedResult) {
    LocalDateTime result = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
    assertEquals(result, expectedResult);
}
```

Any ideas which date pattern should be used?

Comment: what is your dateTimeString and expectedResult?

Comment: @almasshaikh When I try to parse this string "Mon Jan  5 06:41:07 2015" - I want to get this result LocalDateTime.of(2015, 1, 5, 6, 41, 7)

Comment: Would it be too much trouble to insert `dateTimeString.replaceAll(" +", " ")`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the pattern "E MMM ppd HH:mm:ss u". Explanation of p-symbol see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). It means padding the next field up to the width as there are count of p-letters available.

Comment: That's a really elegant solution. Precisely what I was looking for.

Comment: double "pp" before "d" seems counterintuitive to pad only one space "<space>1", "<space>2", ... maybe the meaning is "pp" two characters used, and "d" is day-of-month field ? (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns)

Comment: @MarianoPaniga The symbol p is based on the builder method [padNext(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#padNext-int-) whose argument (the same as the count of pattern letters) specifies the whole width of the field. So two letters pp are required for a two-digit-field.